# Displaying Google Feed JSON in my UITableView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsjsonserialization

I've tried to get the Google `JSON` data and put on my `UITableView`, but it's not showing up.

**Check the google JSON return:**

[image: Google JSON]

I've got the JSON and put on my dictionary already like you would do with a normal JSON, but the google one isn't working.

```
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Design"];

//I've put the results array, not sure if that responseData affects something
self.blogPosts = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
```

and here to add it into my cell

```
cell.textLabel.text = [blogPost valueForKey:@"titleNoFormatting"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [blogPost valueForKey:@"content"];
```

Did anyone know if I need to do something different than a normal JSON feed for google? My code seems right but it's not working

PS: I've did the `NSDictionary` and `NSData` to store the JSON already, I just didn't posted here because I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the JSON data I can say that the way of retrieving the data from the dictionary is wrong.

You should use like the following

```
self.blogPosts = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"responseData"]objectForKey:@"results"];
```

In your case that `self.blogPosts` is nil.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't knew you had to access the first array first in order to get the objects from the second one.

Comment: @RodrigoParra It goes like this - from dataDictionary you are taking the dictionary for key `responseData` and from that dictionary you are taking an array which is stored for key `results`.